# XML without root element in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs, jaxb2

I was wondering whether there is a way to create an object such that a list of such object does not need a root element. For example, if I wanted to create an XML like

```
<Dogs>
  <Dog>A</Dog>
  <Dog>B</Dog>
  <Dog>C</Dog>
</Dogs>
```

I could have the `class Dogs` which would be the root element and has a `List<Dog>`. Now supposed I want to get rid of the encapsulating element `<Dogs>`. So that the list of dog would look like

```
<Dog>A</Dog>
<Dog>B</Dog>
<Dog>C</Dog>
```

how should I construct my classes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not valid XML. Or to be more precise, it's a valid XML *fragment* but not a valid XML *document*. So I don't think JAX-RS will allow that, at least not without doing a lot of weird changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML this is not possible. The specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-document clearly says that a document has *one* root element.

Your second XML-like code is therefore not an XML document, but a concatenation of three XML documents. But parsers aren't usually prepared for this kind of input.

Comment: But I did see xml file without one root element encapsulating all elements.And `golang`'s package parse that with no problem, But I would like to know how to do it on java